# Как flavor выставить realRelease

Tags: android, android-studio

Добрый день, столкнулся с проблемой при сборке билда, подсказали что надо выставить flavor в режим `realRelease`, гугл не очень помог, прошу вашей помощи

Comment: Так с какой проблемой столкнулись? Поподробней вопрос опишите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А саму сборку-то как проводите? И для чего этот билд?

Comment: проблема решена благодаря ответу zTrap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для выбора варианта сборки существует специальная вкладка в Android Studio - **Build Variants**. По-дефолту располагается в левом нижнем углу окна.

Выглядит так:

[image: Build Variants]